# how to append document and update key

Tags: node.js, rest, api, express, mongoose

I am trying to implement a version control type database for record updates. I am using mongoose to do the heavy work. My model looks like the following:

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    const VenueSchema = new Schema({
        _id: String,
        num_revisions: {type: Number, default: 0},
        "1": {
            avp_prio: Number,
            prio_cat: String,
            mkt_prio: Number,
            comp_pos: String,
            pvc_driver: Number,
            pvc_desc: String
        }
    });

    const Venue = mongoose.model('venue', VenueSchema);

    module.exports = Venue;
```

The num_revisions will represent how many revisions have taken place. The Key "1" represent the revision the document is. My goal is to increment num_revisions after a put has occurred and append the res.body to the original document and match the key to the num_revisions value so I know exactly what document is the most recent.

Here is my PUT method thus far. I am able to inc the num_revisions fine but I am not sure how to append the req.body and update the key for it.

```
    /* PUT update docuement with new revision. */
    router.put('/:id', (req, res, next) => {
        console.log(req.body);
        Venue.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id }, { $inc: { num_revisions: 1 },key: 2}, {new: true}).then(function (venue) {   
            res.send(venue);
        });
    });
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

I am trying to complete the following:

```
{
  "_id": "testvenue",
  "__v": 0,
  "num_revisions": 2,
  "1": {
    "avp_prio": 1,
    "prio_cat": "text",
    "mkt_prio": 1,
    "comp_pos": "test",
    "pvc_driver": 1,
    "pvc_desc": "test"
  },
  "2": {
    "avp_prio": 3,
    "prio_cat": "update",
    "mkt_prio": 1,
    "comp_pos": "test",
    "pvc_driver": 1,
    "pvc_desc": "test"
  }
}
```

Comment: You're probably better off making the revisions an array of documents and then use ```$push``` to append new revisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify your life significantly if you revise you schema to this:

```
const VenueSchema = new Schema({
    _id: String,
    revisions: [{
        //... your props
    }]
});
```

This way the `index` of the array would be your `key` and the `array length` would simply be your `num_revisions`.

For the rest of your idea you should look into [mongoose middleware](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) and specifically the [`pre`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre) and [`post`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#post) hooks. They are basically designed for what you are trying to get to. They fire events before and after `save`, `update` etc on models.